# Hibernate Disjunction Condition

Tags: hibernate

I'm wondering if there is a way to add a condition to a hibernate disjunction?

Example

```
    Criterion creator;

             if(securityService.hasRole(RoleConstants.ROLE_CREATOR) {
                 creator = Restrictions.conjunction()
                 .add(Restrictions.eq("creator", this.userInfo.getUser()))
                 .add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.id", DatabaseConstants.STATE_DRAFT));
             }

    Criterion completeCondition = Restrictions.disjunction().add(creator)
                                                            .add(authorizer)
                                                            .add(assessor);
```

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it what your code does already? If not, what do you mean?

Comment: @JB Nizet, See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to use conditions with disjunctions.

```
    Disjunction dis = Restrictions.disjunction(); 
            if(this.securityService.hasRole(RoleConstants.ROLE_AUTHORIZER)) {
                dis.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.id", DatabaseConstants.STATE_AUTHORIZER_REVIEW));
            }

            if(this.securityService.hasRole(RoleConstants.ROLE_ASSIGNOR)) {
                dis.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.id", DatabaseConstants.STATE_ASSIGNOR_REVIEW));
            }

            if(this.securityService.hasRole(RoleConstants.ROLE_ASSESSOR)) {
                dis.add(Restrictions.eq("currentState.id", DatabaseConstants.STATE_ASSESSOR_REVIEW));
            }

    Criteria criteriaStatic = this.session.createCriteria(PurchaseRequest.class)
            .add(Restrictions.isNull("authorizedArchiveDate"))    
            .add(dis);
```